# Riemann surface from Linear fractional transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, modular-group

There is a fact that a subgroup of linear fractional transformation $$\Omega := \Omega(\mathbb{H}) = \{M \in GL_2(\mathbb{R}) : \det(M) > 0\}$$ is a self-homeomorphism of the upper half plane $\mathbb{H} := \{x+iy \in \mathbb{C} : y>0\}.$

Any subgroup $A$ of $\Omega$ which acts on $\mathbb{H}$ nice enough (say properly discontinuous and fixed-point free), the the orbit space $$\mathbb{H}/A \text{ is a Riemann surface}$$ with charts created by pre-image under the natural projection $p : \mathbb{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{H}/A.$

Let $G$ be a subgroup of $\Omega$ which is $$G := \Big<\begin{bmatrix}
    2      & 1  \\
    1       & 1
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 1  \\
    1       & 2
\end{bmatrix} \Big>$$ ($G$ is a commutator subgroup of the modular group; information https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255632506).

I would like to see and verify what is the Riemann surface created by orbit of the action $G$ acts on $\mathbb{H}$ by linear fractional map (what is the surface $\mathbb{H}/G$) ?

I am not quite sure how to start and deal with this kind of questions. Maybe first how to visualize the picture of the resulting Riemann surface. Then the standard technique to construct the homeomorphism of the surface that homeomorphic to $\mathbb{H}/G$.

Comment: Can you please guide with more details ? I am not strong with homology. The currect study is more Riemann surface approach with slight mention of homology. Maybe first any less technical way to see/show something about $\mathbb{H}/G$ (if seeing genus is quite difficult !)

Comment: I have heard of modular group, but have never deal with modular form too !!

Comment: $G$ the commutator subgroup of SL2(Z) [is a congruence subgroup with level 12](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/SL(2,Z).pdf). It means that you can tell directly from $\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\bmod 12$ if $\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$ is in $G$. And it means that we know the generators of its function field in term of $j(z)$ (the function which generates the function field of $\Bbb{H}/SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$). And that you can search in the books on modular curves the construction of the Riemann surface corresponding to $\Bbb{H}/\Gamma(12)$, and the algorithm to compute its homology and genus